# Why is my transition: transform not working in reverse?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

My nav transition is not working in reverse. I'm not sure how to apply any reverse properties, or if it's a more simple fix. Maybe there is another property affecting this. The "is-active" proprty is applied through JS via toggle.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

JS

```
        navLinks.classList.toggle("is-active");
```

Here is the html

```
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="index.php">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="travel.php">travel</a></li>
            <li><a href="photos.php">photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="life.php">about</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

CSS

```
        nav {
         width: 100vw;
         overflow: hidden;
         left: 0;
         margin-top: 18px;
         height: 0;
         transition: height ease-in-out 0.5s;

         .nav-links {
         display: -webkit-box;
         display: -ms-flexbox;
         display: flex;
         -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
         -webkit-box-direction: normal;
         -ms-flex-direction: column;
         flex-direction: column;
         -webkit-box-align: start;
         -ms-flex-align: start;
         align-items: flex-start;
         opacity: 1;
         /* only to show when class is added */
         background-color: black;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         padding-top: 15px;
         list-style: none;
         overflow: hidden;
         -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
         transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
         transition: transform 1s;
         transition: transform 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
         transform: translateY(-100%);
         }
        }

        nav.is-active {
        height: 100vh;
        }

        .nav-links.is-active {
          opacity: 1;
          /*only shows when class is added */
          -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
          transform: translateY(0);
          height: 100vh;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the same transition rules you have on nav and nav-links to nav.is-active and nav-links.is-active. You have to have the same transition rules on both classes for it to smoothly move back and forth.